# Want to convert mysql query to Sequelize query: Add two attribute of row and compare with it another one

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm  trying to write a simple sequelize query but unable to get the expected result.
My Table schema is as follows:

```
my_model:{
id,
material,
in_stock,
reserved,
available,
location
}
```

My query is :

> SELECT *  FROM `my_model` WHERE `in_stock` != `reserved` +
> `available` ORDER BY `location` ASC

My try:

```
        let badRecord = await db['my_model'].findAll({
        where: {
            in_stock: {
                $ne: sequelize.col('available') + sequelize.col('reserved')
            }
        },
        order: [['location','ASC']]})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this literal, probably this will work.

```
let badRecord = await db['my_model'].findAll({
        where: {
            in_stock: {
                $ne: sequelize.literal('available + reserved')
            }
        },
    order: [['location','ASC']]})
```

Comment: yes! it worked for me. please can you explain what does sequelize.literal do?